# doctrine - single table inheritance in a single row

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

What I want to do is to **create a hierachy of roles a person can have**. And do this with Doctrine and Symfony2.

The top of the hierachy would be ***person***. From person there is one subclass called employee and two from this called ***it_user*** and ***telephony_user***. Each one of these add a couple of attributes to the baseclass person.

If I understand correctly, with a *Single Table Inheritance* I would have different rows (one by rol/subclass) for the same person.

I want the same row for the same person, and manage a certain subset of attributes with every class/subclass.

Questions:

Is *Single Table Inheritance* a good way for doing this? Any tweak?

Or otherwise is better the classic way with a superclass called person with an aggregation of all the attributes of all roles?

It is better any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to set different attributes according to *person type*, then you should use  [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). This inheritance lets you make the following:

Superclass:

```
Person
- name
- gender
```

Subclass 1:

```
Employ extends Person
- manager
- projects
```

Subclass 2:

```
TelephonyUser extends Person
- schedule
- foo
- bar
```

By this way, every model (subclasses) is mapped to its table. See how each subclass have custom attributes from each other and sharing parent attributes at the same time.

### Single Table Inheritance (STI) and Aggregation

Take a look at following db schema:

```
-- Uploads table
id  |  name    | size   |  type  |  filename 
------------------------------------------ 
1   | upload1  | 43423  |  image | foo.gif
2   | upload2  | 64234  |  file  | hack.txt
3   | upload3  | 76646  |  image | bar.gif
```

**File** and **Image** are two subclasses of **Upload** class according to *type column*. As you see, both of them have the same attributes with taking care of subclass type. Why? because this Inheritance is wise based in behavior model instead of structure.  For example, you can manage the attribute data differently for each class:

```
// In file class the content as text should be showen
class File extends Uploads{

    // show the file content
    public function show(){
        echo file_get_contents( $this->filename );
    }
}

// In Image class the image should be showen
class File extends Uploads{

    // show the file content
    public function show(){
        echo "<img src='{ $this->filename }' alt='' />";
    }
}
```

See how every class having the same attributes they manage them different from each other. But the most relevant here is that all data will be stored in a `unique table`. So, what you need to do is to model your db squema in order to apply the appropiate Inheritance.